# Analyzing RTP packets from browser's webRTC stream using Wireshark or similar tool

Tags: webrtc, wireshark, rtp, libpcap

Is my observation correct that RTP/RTCP packets from a webRTC stream cannot be analyzed in Wireshark running on the same desktop to analyze RTP packets because the browser would have encrypted them using DTLS/SRTP?

I know there are some browser APIs to help but is there any other approach? 
 libpcap if used to write some tool will probably have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox has support for dumping the decrypted RTP/RTCP packets into the log files, described [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/debugging-encrypted-rtp-is-more-fun-than-it-used-to-be/). Chrome does not have something similar unfortunately.

If you use a server, some of them like Janus have the ability to generate similar dumps, see [here](https://www.meetecho.com/blog/capturing-webrtc-traffic-in-janus/)

Comment: I guess that keeping a middleware in between will need to do the entire DTLS-SRTP handshake, copy the rtp/rtcp packets and blindly forward them to the other peer but then we are dealing with all related issues which Janus-type SFUs/MCUs deal with. The Firefox solution should suffice. Thanks

Comment: Can u please help me on this [question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673672/webrtc-relationship-between-channels-tracks-streams-vis-a-vis-rtp-ssrc-and-r)